# Unique items from multiple lists in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I need to create a function to get a list of all unique items from multiple lists. Let's consider the following example:

```
$list-1: top, left, color;
$list-2: top, color, border;

@function get-unique-items($lists...) {
    $unique-items: ();
    // do the magic
    @return $unique-items;
}

@debug get-unique-items($list-1, $list-2);

// should return: top, left, color, border
```

Can anyone do the magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
@function get-unique-items($lists...) {
    $unique-items: ();
    
    @each $list in $lists {
        @each $item in $list {
            @if not index($unique-items, $item) {
                $unique-items: append($unique-items, $item, comma);
            }
        }
    }
    
    @return $unique-items;
}
```